# Node.js - Cannot read property 'toString' of null when running package on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, installation

I am using the `gulp` and `hercule` package on node.js to transclude some plain text files. On Unix, everything seems to work fine. However, some coworkers are having issues running it on Windows. They are getting the following error message only when running on Windows:

```
[13:02:01] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null at Object.transcludeStringSync (D:\project\node_modules\hercule\lib\hercule.js:136:36)
```

I have tried the above with `hercule@3.0.5` as well as `hercule@2.0.5`, and both packages give the above error. However, given that this occurs only on Windows and across many versions of the package, I suspect this issue *has something to due with the Node.js installation or path*.

The code that is using the `hercule` package:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var drakov = require('drakov');
var hercule = require('hercule');

gulp.task('mock', ['i18n','build_minify_no_tests'], function() {
    var mockSpecificationTemplate= fs.readFileSync('test/mock/mock-template.apib','utf8');
    var transcludedMockSpecification = hercule.transcludeStringSync(mockSpecificationTemplate, {
        relativePath: path.resolve('../../../')
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('test/mock/mock.apib', transcludedMockSpecification, 'utf-8');

    // Running mock server
    var drakovArgv = {
        sourceFiles: 'test/mock/mock.apib',
        serverPort: 9000,
        staticPaths: [
            '../../'
        ],
        discover: true,
        watch: true
    };
    drakov.run(drakovArgv);
});
```

`node` and `npm` version information:

```
$ node -v
v6.3.0
$ npm -v
3.10.3
```

Comment: The issue probably is that `transcludeStringSync` will try to spawn another node process using `child_process` and that will probably fail on windows due to the path or arguments who knows. Anyway it's bad practice, just use `transcludeString` instead  and it should be fixed.

Comment: It is trying to convert file content toString(). but its getting null, hence the issue is that the file path is not returning anything.

Can you show test/mock/mock-template.apib content? i believe something is wrong with the paths there (from linux to windows) the relative path + those paths are not configuring correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hercule.transcludeStringSync` simply runs another `hercule` process and sends input to it:

```
const result = childProcess.spawnSync('../bin/hercule', syncArgs, syncOptions);
```

with the script `../bin/hercule`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

"use strict";

require('../lib/main.js');
```

...obviously doesn't work on Windows

If that task must be synchronized, you may use the following function instead:

```
function transcludeStringSync(input, options) {
  const {dirname, join} = require('path')
  const hercule = join(dirname(require.resolve('hercule')), 'main')
  const args = [hercule, '--reporter', 'json-err']
  for (let name in options) {
    args.push(`--${name}`, `--${options[name]}`)
  }
  const result = require('child_process').spawnSync('node', args, {input})
  const err = result.stderr.toString()
  if (err) throw new Error('Could not transclude input')

  return result.stdout.toString()
}
```

Comment: This (and a combination of Windows line endings) solved the issue. Accepted.